# Regular expression for string replacement

Tags: c#, regex

I have some 100 files in which I need to replace:

1. Eval("something")                with      Eval("something").ToEncodedString()
2. Eval("something").ToString()     with      Eval("something").ToEncodedString()

I'm writing a small C# application that can automate this. But unable to form the regular expression. Would somebody help me please?

Comment: Why not open these files in Notepad++ and Replace the text there applying it to all opened files

Comment: The string within the quotes can be anything. So I need to use a regular expression. If I'm using TextPad what would be the search regex term and the replacement regex term?

Comment: Have you tried something? Showing http://whathaveyoutried.com makes people see you've tried and that you are not after "code for me/free" answers.

Comment: BTW, I can give you a hint: `\w` matches any word character and `+` means 1 or more times. See here for more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: I tried using Regex.Replace(txt, "([Eval(]\"[a-z0-9]+\"[)])?", ""); But not sure how to specify the replacement string as well as a regexp.

Comment: If you have sed ( a stream editor) then you can do this `sed -re "s/(Eval[(]\"[^\"]*\"[)])([^.]|$)/\1.ToEncodedString()/g"` does first half. search for `"(Eval[(]\"[^\"]*\"[)])([^.]|$)"` replace with `"\1.ToEncodedString()"` sed is a Unix/Gnu/Linux command, no need to write a program.

Comment: if you post you code snippet that would be helpful. There could be many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `@"\bEval\(""(?<Value>.+?)""\)(?:\.ToString\(\))?"`

Breakdown:

- `\bEval`: match a word-boundary to ensure we match "Eval" as a whole word and not as part of another word
- `\(""`: literal opening parenthesis and double quotes (the double quotes appear twice since that's how they're escaped when using a verbatim string literal, i.e., the @ symbol preceding the string)
- `(?<Value>.+?)`: named capture group of "Value" which is a non-greedy match of any character (will stop at double quotes)
- `""\)`: closing double quotes and closing parenthesis
- `(?:\.ToString\(\))?`: the `(?:...)` bit is a non-capturing group, then we match `.ToString()` literally with appropriate escaping, and the final `?` makes this group optional

The replacement pattern is `@"Eval(""${Value}"").ToEncodedString()"`, which is easy to understand. The important part is that the named capture group, "Value," is referenced by using `${Value}`.

Example code:

```
string[] inputs = 
{
    @"Eval(""something"")",
    @"Eval(""hello"").ToString()"
};

string pattern = @"\bEval\(""(?<Value>.+?)""\)(?:\.ToString\(\))?";
string replacement = @"Eval(""${Value}"").ToEncodedString()";

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement));
}
```

Comment: @Nevyn when using the [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) (i.e., the @ symbol preceding the string) you can escape double quotes by using them twice. Without the verbatim string literal, you would escape double quotes with a back-slash as `\"hello\"`, but with them it's `""hello""`. To clarify why I use them to begin with, it makes it easier to use escape sequences rather than doubling up on backslashes, and regex tends to have many backslashes for metacharacters.

Comment: ok, that does make a lot of sense.  Didn't know you could do that.  Looks weird though :-)

Comment: @ahmad Thanks so much. I was struggling a lot with matching the opening and closing parantheses. Thanks.